# Reordering data.frame columns first by a fixed-order of subgroups, then alphabetically inside each subgroup

Tags: r

I've the need of reordering the columns of a huge data.frame based on two conditions. The first is a fixed order based of column prefixes (which I use like a kind of column categories). inside each category, the order is alphabethical.

In other words:

- First on a fixed order based on prefixes -> "" {no prefix}, "details", "attributes", "stats", "poll", "endpoint"
- Then, inside each subgroup by alphabetical order

Here's a reproducible data.set for playing with:

```
blah <- data.frame("id"=1,                                                         
                   "details.thumbnail"=1,                                          
                   "details.image"=1,
                   "type"=1,                                                       
                   "name"=1,                                               
                   "attributes.num"=1,                                             
                   "attributes.boardgamemechanic"=1,                               
                   "attributes.boardgameexpansion"=1,                              
                   "stats.averageweight.value"=1,                                  
                   "poll.results.suggested_numplayers.7.Recommended.numvotes"=1,
                   "poll.results.suggested_numplayers.7.NotRecommended.numvotes"=1,
                   "attributes.boardgamemechanic"=1,   
                   "endpoint.uri"=1)
```

I'm really puzzled as every solution I write is really weird and definitively not elegant.

Comment: 1. manually (I know, I feel really a lame today) 2. splitting in substrings using regex and the reordering any block (ugly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
cols <- c("^([^.]+)$", "^(details)", "^(attributes)", "^(stats)", "^(poll)", "^(endpoint)")
s <- names(blah)
n <- seq_along(cols)
for(i in n) s <- sub(cols[i], paste0(n[i], "\\1"), s)
new_vec <- substr(s[order(s)], 2, nchar(s[order(s)]))
new_vec
#  [1] "id"                                                         
#  [2] "name"                                                       
#  [3] "type"                                                       
#  [4] "details.image"                                              
#  [5] "details.thumbnail"                                          
#  [6] "attributes.boardgameexpansion"                              
#  [7] "attributes.boardgamemechanic"                               
#  [8] "attributes.boardgamemechanic.1"                             
#  [9] "attributes.num"                                             
# [10] "stats.averageweight.value"                                  
# [11] "poll.results.suggested_numplayers.7.NotRecommended.numvotes"
# [12] "poll.results.suggested_numplayers.7.Recommended.numvotes"   
# [13] "endpoint.uri"
```

We use regex to look for the prefixes and non-prefixed column names. The `cols` variable is created in the order outlined in the question. Adding a number to each find. When no prefix is found `1` is attached, for `details`, `2` is attached. And so on. I use a `for` loop as it is best used for operating in one iteration and saving the result for the next. It is easy to `order` this new vector of names. Then the number that was attached is taken off for subsetting with `blah[,new_vec]`.

Comment: cool! it works like a charm (and very elegant use of that prefix!). Tnx allot